# multiple partial in jquery ajax rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery

How to update multiple partial through ajax in rails 3.2
Here i did my ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/home/create_entry",
    type: "POST",
    data: params,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#'+did).html(data);
        //   $("#results").html('<%#=j render(:partial => 'explorer', :locals => {:entries => @entries, :entry_count=> @entry_count}) %>');
    }
});
```

In controller written

```
def create_entry
 if request.xhr?  
  @entry = Entry.new
  @entry.title = params[:title]
   respond_to do |format|
            if @entry.save
              flash[:notice] = "Entry created successfully"
              @entry = Entry.last
              @entries = Entry.where(:user_id => current_user.id).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction)
              @entry_count = @entries.count
              format.js
            end
          end
    end
```

And in create_entry.js.erb

```
<%= render :partial =>  'edit_entry_form', :locals => {:entry => @entry}%>
<%= render :partial =>  'explorer', :locals => {:entries => @entries}%>
```

Now i can able to get both data, How can i update both partial after success of ajax request  ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using jQuery to dynamically insert the contents of these two partials into the areas of the page you want to update. Something like:

```
$("#divforedit_entry_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'edit_entry_form' :locals => {:entry => @entry})%>");

$("#divforexplorer").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'explorer' :locals => {:entries => @entries})%>");
```

Answer (score 0):

First off we need to correct your AJAX call as we don't need to have the server response added onto the page only evaluated (which in Rails happens by default).

#### Javascript

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/home/create_entry",
  type: "POST",
  data: params,
  cache: false
});
```

Now we update the controller to perform the logic and get any required data to correctly render the partials.

#### Controller

```
def create_entry
  if request.xhr?  
    # Create entry
    respond_to do |format|
      if @entry.save
        # Collect any data needed for view
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now in the view we use jQuery and the Rails javascript helper to replace/insert the partials into the HTML document.

#### View (create_entry.js.erb)

```
$("#edit_entry_form").replaceWith("<%= j(render('edit_entry_form', :entry => @entry)) %>");
$("#explorer").replaceWith("<%= j(render('explorer', :entries => @entries)) %>");
```

The above presumes that the HTML IDs `#edit_entry_form` and `#explorer` exist.